# make: define multiple variables with pattern specific variable values

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

How do you define multiple variables using `make`'s pattern specific variable values feature https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern_002dspecific.html#Pattern_002dspecific?  For example, suppose that `LIBDIR` and `RPATH` have already been defined, and I want to set the following:

```
LDFLAGS += -L$(LIBDIR) $(RPATH)
LDLIBS += -lsomelibrary
```

for builds that match the pattern `utest%`.  So for example,

```
utest% : -L$(LIBDIR) $(RPATH)
```

would get me halfway there, but then how to define the second variable?

---

I thought that maybe using multi-line variables https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multi_002dLine.html would work, but I can't quite get there.  I've tried:

```
define linking_vars :=
LDFLAGS := -L$(LIBDIR) $(RPATH)
LDLIBS := -lsomelibrary
endef

utest% : $(linking_vars)
```

and also

```
define newline = 

endef

utest_% : LDFLAGS := -L$(LIBDIR) $(RPATH) $(newline) LDLIBS := -lsomelibrary
```

but I haven't had any luck yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you want to do, but it sounds as if this might do it:

```
utest% : LDFLAGS += -L$(LIBDIR) $(RPATH)
utest% : LDLIBS += -lsomelibrary
```

Comment: Yep, I was making this much harder than it needed to be!  The way I was reading the documentation I though that make reads the first match of the same stem length in the order that they occur in the makefile, but in fact its read _all_ of the matches of the same stem length in the order that they occur in the makefile.  Thanks for showing me the light!